# How to use FFMPEG to capture a browser's tab content

Tags: windows, firefox, ffmpeg, screen-recording

I'm working on a project where I need to record HTML5 animations that are going to play in different browser's tabs.

So I've been reading a bit, and apparently it could be done using FFMPEG, maybe using the gdigrab device: 
https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#gdigrab

Where you can even grab from a specific window (*like record calc.exe using title=Calculator*)

I want to use this logic to capture each of the multiple browser tabs contents. (*or at least one*) But I don't know the Firefox/Chrome tabs "title" or if they even work as windows.

I'd also need to record audio, so I would need to either mix the computer's output device with the video from the tab.

If anyone has more information on how I could do this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,

Comment: Must you use Windows?  Must you use Firefox?  What are you going to do with the output afterwards?

Comment: Hi Mulvya, no, right now I'm exploring what is the best alternative, and thought I'd start with what I'm more familiar. As of now, I stopped using FFMPEG and I'm using a Javascript library called RecordRTC to record and save the video blob output in a server and made a Google Chrome extension using the DesktopCapture API, which I think it's a simpler approach.What I need to do is to somehow make a script that some how accepts an URL as an input parameter, then opens that URL in a new tab (headless), records its contents, and finally closes it and saves the video output to a server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tabs are within the browser's application logic so I don't think you can target a tab. If you detach the tab as a separate window, you can capture it. You need the string that shows up in Task Manager. This is the Window Title.

First run `tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe" /fo list | findstr  Window`

This will produce a set of lines of all the separate windows controlled by firefox.exe

Suppose you wanted to capture this current page, the findstr output would be

```
Window Title: firefox - How to use FFMPEG to capture a browser's tab content - Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox
```

Then run

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i title="firefox - How to use FFMPEG to capture a browser's tab content - Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox" -pix_fmt yuv420p tabgrab.mp4
```

You can move the window while recording but if you resize it, the recording will end at that point. If there are other tabs in that window, and you switch to them, they will get captured. So, best to isolate the desired tab into its own window.

For audio, you will need to use a [directshow](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#dshow) input device. See docs and the examples on how to list them.

Comment: Thanks! that works perfectly to find the right name of the window. But I still have the problem of having to record "one by one". (or 2 by 2 if using different browsers window) You are right when you say tabs are within the browser's application logic so my best bet would be to find a Firefox extension or API that lets me integrate with FFMPEG. And even then I'd have to deal with overlapping audio sources, but thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You can specify as many separate window inputs as you like of a browser, as long as they have different window titles and route them to different output files. Your capture performance will suffer, depending on your CPU/RAM..etc

Comment: Is there any chance to capture two browser windows opened on the same site? As an example scenario, two instances of a browser running e2e tests on the same site.

Comment: You would specify two inputs (`-f gdigrab -i title`) - one for each window.