# Capture Chromium (or any internet browser) into a transport strem

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, gstreamer, chromium, transport

I'm looking for a solution to capture the video (and audio) from an `HTML5`page read/rendered by Chromium -or any other browser or application- into an `MPEG2/MPEG4` transport stream.

I've look on `ffmpeg` or `gstreamer` without luck... not sure if its even possible!

Any one wants to try at this one? I can have this running on any OS.

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/43265132/5726027

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm working on the same, you can check the HTML5 Api to Capture Video and Audio. With that you access devices camera such as Ios, Android, etc.

Try this

```
<input type="file" name="Videofile" accept="video/*" class="box__file" id="Videofile" data-multiple-caption=" {count} files selected " multiple" required>
```

For more info visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API

And then you can upload to server or In my case I'm using Nodejs for server side which helps me to stream data.